# Is there any fix for wrong location of dropdown menu of a rtl select?

Tags: css, html-select, right-to-left

Open the `select` below in Chrome: (It may happen only in Chrome in MacOS)

```css
select {
    direction: rtl;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>item one</option>
    <option>item two</option>
</select>
```

It opens like this for me:
[image]

Is there any fix for this? I expect it to open under the select not right to it.

Comment: For me it works as you expected. Ubuntu/Chrome 52.0.

Comment: Then it must only happen in mac, which is good news :D Users of my site are using windows. I guess it should work as expected in Windows too. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more explanation to the overall final look of this dropdown should be beyond the dropdown going to the bottom? `direction:` has relatively poor support these days: http://caniuse.com/#search=direction and I'd recommend just removing it and letting the drop down work naturally in the browsers at this point if possible.

Comment: It should open at the bottom of the control, not next to it. (currently it opens at the right side of the control.)